# Azure DevOps - How to update pipeline repo source without re-create a new one?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am planning to move my Azure pipeline source files to a new Azure repo.   How can I update the existing pipeline setting to point to the new Azure private repo location? I prefer not to re-create the repo and variables.  Right now, if I edit the current pipeline setting, it would only allow me to select .yml files from the current repo.  There's not option to change repo.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description, the pipeline is  Yaml type.

You could navigate to `Triggers -> YAML -> Get sources`.

[image]

[image]

Then you could select the target Azure repo.

If the Yaml file has different name, you could also select the target yaml file in the `Settings`.

Comment: This worked for me! Note that you might need to use or create a different Service Connection in case the previously used service connection doesn't have sufficient permission for the new repository.

Comment: @Eilon . Thanks for your info.